# Java: Poor error handling, Throw inside Finally

Tags: java, fortify

I have the following code which I am running through fortify. Why it gets marked for poor error handling, throw inside finally?

```
private String getResourceContent(String fileName) throws IOException {

    try (InputStream resource = ErrorResource.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
        return new String(resource.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        throw new ErrorDescriptorException(
                String.format("Error loading Error description data from Resource file [%s].", fileName), n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking `null` using a NPE instead of a basic if-else? Theres rarely ever a valid reason to catch a NPE. Just do `if (resource == null) { ... }`.

Comment: See [Throwing an exception inside finally](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188858/throwing-an-exception-inside-finally) from [softwareengineering.se].

Answer (score 7):

### Explanation

This is explained very well in the official documentation (see [Poor Error Handling: Throw Inside Finally](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.structural.java.poor_error_handling_throw_inside_finally)). Let me quickly quote the important sections:

> Using a `throw` statement inside a `finally` block breaks the logical progression through the try-catch-finally.
>
> In Java, finally blocks are **always executed** after their corresponding try-catch blocks and are often used to **free allocated resources**, such as file handles or database cursors. Throwing an exception in a finally block can **bypass critical cleanup code** since normal program execution will be **disrupted**.

So you can easily bypass cleanup code by doing that, which leads to resource leaks.

Although not directly visible in your code, you actually have a *hidden* `finally` block since you are using *try-with-resources* which automatically closes the resource in a finally block.

Also see [Throwing an exception inside finally](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188858/throwing-an-exception-inside-finally) where this was already discussed.

---

### Example

Here is an example from the official documentation:

```
public void processTransaction(Connection conn) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        fis = new FileInputStream("badFile.txt");
        ...
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
        log("File not found.");
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        // handle error
    } finally {
        if (fis == null) {
            // This bypasses cleanup code
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }

        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                // Not executed if the exception is thrown
                stmt.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                log(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `stmt.close()` is **bypassed** when the `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

---

### Note

Why are you checking for `null` using a `NullPointerException` instead of a basic *if-else*? There is rarely ever a valid reason to catch a `NullPointerException`. Just do:

```
try (InputStream resource = ErrorResource.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
    if (resource == null) {
        // TODO Throw your exception here
    }
    return new String(resource.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

It might also help to improve the error message by telling the exact reason that the resource could not be found.

Comment: NPE can also be there at ErrorResource.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName). ErrorResource.classLoader can be null if loaded by bootstrap classloader?

Comment: But how does the exception thrown in the `catch` block interrupt the `finally` block? An exception thrown in the finally block would escape the whole statement, not get caught by the `catch` block.

Comment: @KaranKhanna Then check it there as well. Do not use exceptions for regular control flow, use if-else whenever possible. And for NPE it is almost always possible.

Comment: @Zabuza I changed it to: try (InputStream resource = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
                if (resource == null) {
                    throw new ErrorDescriptorException(
                            String.format("Error loading Error description data from Resource file [%s].", fileName));
                }
                return new String(resource.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }  Still the same issue.

Comment: Does it go away if you temporarily remove the `throw new Error...` all from the method? Could you edit your question and include more info? Like the full class and the full warning message? Maybe it points to a different location.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code, which is loosely based on yours:

```
String throwing(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream resource = inputStream) {
        return "good";
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        return "bad";
    }
}
```

You see, no exceptions thrown here. Still, you *cannot* remove the `throws IOException` bit – how’s that? Well, `InputStream#close()` can throw it, and it will be in the implicit `finally` block that the try-with-resources statement created. I guess there’s not much you can do about it, it looks like a Fortify false positive.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the *misleading* message from your tool, there is actually is poor error handling in your code, for multiple of reasons:

- catching NPE is really **bad** practice. Either it is a bug (something that is null and shouldn't), or your code is missing a check `if (whatever == null)` and the corresponding code to deal with that *expected* situation
- assuming that this NPE has exactly that meaning that you express in your new Exception is well, just guessing

In other words: without further information, it is not clear *what exactly* your tool complains about. But: one doesn't need a tool to understand: this is poor error handling.

Beyond that, such tools typically give some sort of information about their warnings. Meaning: there might be an "error id" coming with that warning, and you should be able to look up that "error id" in the documentation of your tool for further explanations.

Comment: Your comments may be correct in general, but do not answer the question. The question would not change substantially if it was any other exception type.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I disagree. What if that code would be throwing some "internal" runtime exception, and the whole point of the try/catch is to turn an expected runtime exception into some checked version?

Comment: There was nothing to agree to in my comment. OP asked “Why does Fortify give an error on throwing in finally”, and your answer says nothing on that topic. That’s not my opinion, but a fact.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel When you turn to the source code ... there isn't a *finally* statement in there. My answer addresses broader context. Like: why could that code be off "poor quality", and how to deal with such problems (turn to the documentation of your tool) in general. The OP already received a more specific answer, but always keep in mind that there are other, future readers which might come here with *slightly* different questions.